# Generate 4 digit unique random number in Java using predefined library?

Tags: java, random

I want to generate 4 digit unique random number in Java.

Suppose I run the application for 1000 times then each time I should get unique random number.

I tried with UUID but it is very long random code. I want the random code in 4 digits.

So far I tried with following code -

```
int num = -1;

ArrayList<Integer> arNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    arNumber.add(x);
}
Collections.shuffle(arNumber);

String strNum = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    strNum = strNum + arNumber.get(new Random().nextInt(10));

num = Integer.parseInt(strNum);
```

This code works fine, but I doubt it will repeat a number after some thousand.

Is there any built-in/predefined functionality/library/algorithm available in Java?

Comment: (i) populate a list with numbers from 0 to 9999 (ii) shuffle (iii) iterate.

Comment: @assylias - upper bound should be 9999.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answers. I'll try some of your methods and get back to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my understaning if you want to generate a 4 digit unique random number it means numbers between 0 and 9999. In this case this

```
ArrayList<Integer> arNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) { 
    ...
```

will produce only 10 numbers in the list.  I would do it like this

```
class RandomGenerator {
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;

    RandomGenerator() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            ints.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(ints);
    }

    int nextInt() {
        return ints.get(i++);
    }
}
```

Comment: This. Except you *might* want to put an overflow check into `nextInt()` so you don't get an index out of bounds exception when you run out of numbers. Depends on your use case, I guess.

Comment: I already have tried this method, but each time I want a number it will create an object of class and it will create new list. So possibility of duplicates

Comment: Well, you should create a RandomGenerator instance once RandomGenerator rg = new RandomGenerator(); then call rg.next() <= 1000 times; if this is a problem then you can make it Singleton or just chagnge everything what's inside to static.

Comment: Your code is correct but as he said 4 digit random number, so it should start from 1000 not 0, just replace 0 with 1000 in the loop :)

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there exist a lot of libraries concerning security questions but if it is not that critical:

```
Random r = new Random();
List<Integer> codes = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int x = r.nextInt(9999);
    while (codes.contains(x))
        x = r.nextInt(9999);
    codes.add(x);
}
String str = String.format("%04d", codes.get(0));
```

This should give you random numbers and with String.format you can pad them to be 4-digits wide.

Comment: This would work, but would take longer and longer to complete as it got closer to finishing all the codes

Comment: Thats right - to improve this store min and max values of already generated numbers, and use these as boundaries for the random generator. (This still may not have an impact if the inital boundary numbers are still present!)

Answer (score 1):

Try with Secure Random.
It will generate a [strong random number](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MSC02-J.+Generate+strong+random+numbers), and it will give you next decimal < 9999, and by using HashSet you assure that there will not be duplicates

```
try 
{
     SecureRandom randomGenerator = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");         
     HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
     while(set.size()<10)
         set.add(randomGenerator.nextInt(9999)));

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
  // Forward to handler
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this code to achieve random number in java.
 Pass numOfCharacters value(suppose 4)

```
public static String getRandomalphanumericNumber(int numOfCharacters) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        Random random = new Random();
        char[] chars = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
                'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
                'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
                'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
                'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4',
                '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCharacters; i++) {
            buffer.append(chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)]);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return something that was alphanumeric and also not guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: but i was checked the code gives unique value..

Comment: Where does this check happen? Clearly repeats won't come up very often, but I can't see the code to prevent that happening